# Are questions about specific models of hardware okay?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

I'd like to know whether Logitech K310 "washable" keyboard is still washable with one of the keys removed.

Would such question be okay?

Answer (score 4):

Questions about specific hardware models are okay, as long as the question is answerable and well-written.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of being too specific, try and see if you can make a question as canonical as possible. We want them to be applicable to a worldwide audience—not just the owners of a K310 keyboard.

Try asking *how to find out whether your keyboard is washable* instead.

Comment: Well, that would be quite hard. Logitech claims that K310 is washable with some restrictions - warm water, soap only (no serious detergents), submerging it for not too long and not too deep. They don't say anything about whether it can be washed with some of the keys removed.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess that's probably better as a specific question then.